# Android project is all messed up- not recognizing anything in my resource files and the design editor says "not available until next gradle sync"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Title sums it up pretty well. I imported a project into android studio for one of my classes where I needed to make some changes. However, everything seems messed up. Like I said, nothing in my resource file is getting recognized. For example, strings. My strings.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="app_name">My Order</string>
    <string name="name">Name</string>
    <string name="toppings">Toppings</string>
    <string name="pepperonis">Pepperonis</string>
    <string name="sausage">Sausage</string>
    <string name="jalapenos">Jalapenos</string>
    <string name="onions">Onions</string>
    <string name="mushrooms">Mushrooms</string>
    <string name="garlic">Garlic</string>
    <string name="quantity">Quantity</string>
    <string name="initial_quantity_value">2</string>
    <string name="order">Order</string>
    <string name="order_summary_name">Name:<xliff:g example="Vijaya" id="name">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="yes">Yes</string>
    <string name="no">No</string>
    <string name="order_summary_whipped_cream">Add Whipped Cream? <xliff:g example="yes" id="addWhippedCream">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="order_summary_chocolate">Add chocolate? <xliff:g example="yes" id="addChocolate">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="order_summary_quantity">Quantity: <xliff:g example="2" id="quantity">%d</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="order_summary_total_price">Total: $ <xliff:g example="10" id="price">%.2f</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="thank_you">Thank you!</string>
    <string name="too_much_coffee">Please select less than one hundred cups of coffee</string>
    <string name="too_little_toppings">Please select at least one topping</string>
</resources>
```

And then in my activity_main.xml, I have this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.vijaya.myorder.MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/user_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
            android:text="@string/toppings" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/pepperonis_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/pepperonis"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sausage_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/sausage"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
...
...
```

None of those strings are recognized, for example. Not the sausage, pepperoni, toppings, etc. Specifically, "cannot resolve symbol @string/..."

Same goes with @id, @style, etc.

I'm really not sure where to begin with fixing this. This is my second ever assignment with android studio so all these concepts are pretty foreign to me and I feel that I shouldn't be having such issues.

Comment: just wait for the gradle sync to finish or you can clean build and then rebuild your project and wait untill sync is completed

Comment: @AppDev that's another question. There's no option at all for me to build the project. Could it be that I opened up the project in the wrong directory?